# How to find the sum of a series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2^n} +\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^n}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the sum of a series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2^n} +\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^n}\right)$$ and I don't really understand how to do it. I tried to establish a pattern for the first members of the sequence, but it did not work (they have some kind of pattern, but it will not help me much, I think). Now I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Try breaking up the series into two smaller series. I think you'll find you know what to do with the smaller series

Comment: Have you heard of "geometric series"?

Comment: Yes, I've heard about geometric series, but here a series is an alternating series.

Comment: A geometric series can be also alternating one. This does not change anything.

Comment: @EnoriRenobu $\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n} = \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n.$ Do you know what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Let $$ S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2^n} +\frac{(-1)^{n}}{3^n}\right)$$
Use $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^k=\frac{z}{1-z}, |z|<1$$
Then $$S=\frac{1/2}{1-1/2}+\frac{-1/3}{1+1/3}=1-1/4=3/4.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac x{1-x}, &
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n x^n &=-x\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n=-\frac x{1+x}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac12+\dfrac14=\frac34, \frac12+\dfrac14+\dfrac18=\frac78, \frac12+\dfrac14+\dfrac18+\dfrac1{16}=\frac{15}{16},\cdots$$

has the obvious pattern $$1-2^{-n}.$$

$$-\frac13+\dfrac19=-\frac29, -\frac13+\dfrac19-\dfrac1{27}=-\frac7{27}, -\frac13+\dfrac19-\dfrac1{27}+\frac1{81}=-\frac{20}{81},\cdots$$

has the less obvious pattern $$-\frac14+\frac{(-3)^{-n}}4.$$